# Hibernate 4.2 exception: Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have been struggling to fix this error from long time Kindly help me in this.

I am getting `ERROR: HHH000196: Error parsing XML (2) : Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared.`

Please help me to fix this:

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

My cfg.xml header:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

My hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.kivar.lumina.server.segment.Segment" table="segments">
        <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Location URL of DTD is wrong. In hbm.xml hibernate-*mapping*-3.0.dtd should be used instead of hibernate-*configuration*-3.0.dtd as in following:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution in accepted answer is safe. Of course, there should be DTD for mapping rather than configuration, but the URL is

> http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd

since Hibernate 3.6. See https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide36